# Method gethome of facebook4j throws OAuthException

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook4j to integrate Facebook on my Android app.

After I've succesfully login, I can post messages to my wall, retrive notification and so on.
Otherwise, when I try to retrive my Home News, using the method getHome() of the class Facebook, it throws the following exception:

```
FacebookException{statusCode=500, response=HttpResponse{statusCode=500, responseAsString='{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}', is=libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream@41c81938, streamConsumed=true}, errorType='OAuthException', errorMessage='An unknown error has occurred.', errorCode=1, errorSubcode=-1}
at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:189)
at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:93)
at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.get(FacebookImpl.java:2431)
at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.getHome(FacebookImpl.java:677)
```

Moreover, I can call the method getFeed correctly.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I can see an `OAuthException`, so I would say there is something wrong with the token you are using.

Did you request the `read_stream` permission?

> A user access token with read_stream permission is required to view
>   that person's news feed.
>
> *Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/home/*

Comment: please help with this facebook4j related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45807817/6144372